How to properly build Google V8 as a static library on a Mac OS in 2024?
I have been trying to follow the instructions to build V8 as described on the official web site with the intent of embedding it on my application but I keep getting a linker error.
I followed the environment setup described on the link below and was able to run the tests:
https://v8.dev/docs/build
After that, I tried to run the embedding guide using this link:
https://v8.dev/docs/embed
At step (5) of the embedding guide I get an error. The linker says that libv8_libbase.a and libv8_libplatform.a file types are unknown.
Here are some details of my environment:
System: Darwin Hostname.lan 23.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.4.0: Fri Mar 15 00:11:05 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.101.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 (MacBook Pro With Intel chip)
Xcode version: 15.0
V8 revision: 1d8f52fa183e0534a931880bdf77710a235bb0e6 (from issuing git checkout branch-heads/11.9 -b sample -t as described on the embedding guide)
GN arguments:
dcheck_always_on = false
is_component_build = false
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_custom_libcxx = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false

Result of step (5) with verbose switch
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx14.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello-world.cc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=14.0 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 1015.6 -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/Users/username/develop/cpp/v8 -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I . -I include -D V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -D V8_ENABLE_SANDBOX -I/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/username/develop/cpp/v8 -ferror-limit 19 -pthread -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fno-rtti -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/h2/k842z7212bx0_nj_t_966k5w0000gn/T/hello-world-c174a4.o -x c++ samples/hello-world.cc
clang -cc1 version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin23.4.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 include
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 14.0.0 14.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o hello_world -Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/h2/k842z7212bx0_nj_t_966k5w0000gn/T/hello-world-c174a4.o -lv8_monolith -lv8_libbase -lv8_libplatform -ldl -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: multiple errors: unknown file type in '/Users/username/develop/cpp/v8/out.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/libv8_libplatform.a'; unknown file type in '/Users/username/develop/cpp/v8/out.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/libv8_libbase.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


UPDATE 2024-MAY-26
I spent this whole weekend exploring this subject and found out a few things:
1. The files libv8_libplatform.a and libv8_libbase.a are not exactly archive files. They are thin archive files. This is what the file command tells me:
$ file out/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a
out/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a: thin archive with 358 symbol entries

$ file out/x64.release/obj/libv8_libbase.a
out/x64.release/obj/libv8_libbase.a: thin archive with 358 symbol entries

So maybe is this why the linking phase fails?
2. I stumbled upon this page by sheer luck where these guys explain that those two archives are no longer needed to perform the compilation anymore. I'm still skeptical about this because when I try to compile without those files I get a long list of unresolved symbols from the linker. Too long to fit this post so I'm pasting only a couple of "paragraphs" here:
ld: Undefined symbols:
  v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__1::default_delete<v8::TracingController>>, v8::platform::PriorityMode), referenced from:
      _main in hello-world-2d7a6c.o
  std::__Cr::__shared_weak_count::__get_deleter(std::type_info const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_pointer<v8::internal::BackingStore*, std::__Cr::default_delete<v8::internal::BackingStore>, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::BackingStore>> in libv8_monolith.a[57](api.o)
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_pointer<v8::internal::Coverage*, std::__Cr::default_delete<v8::internal::Coverage>, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::Coverage>> in libv8_monolith.a[141](debug-interface.o)
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_emplace<v8::internal::Counters, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::Counters>> in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_emplace<v8::internal::metrics::Recorder, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::metrics::Recorder>> in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_pointer<v8::internal::CompilationStatistics*, std::__Cr::shared_ptr<v8::internal::CompilationStatistics>::__shared_ptr_default_delete<v8::internal::CompilationStatistics, v8::internal::CompilationStatistics>, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::CompilationStatistics>> in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_emplace<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::CppgcPlatformAdapter, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::CppgcPlatformAdapter>> in libv8_monolith.a[203](cpp-heap.o)
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_emplace<v8::internal::SingleCopyReadOnlyArtifacts, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::SingleCopyReadOnlyArtifacts>> in libv8_monolith.a[253](read-only-heap.o)
      ...
  std::__Cr::locale::use_facet(std::__Cr::locale::id&) const, referenced from:
      std::__Cr::basic_ostream<char, std::__Cr::char_traits<char>>& std::__Cr::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__Cr::char_traits<char>>(std::__Cr::basic_ostream<char, std::__Cr::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in libv8_monolith.a[11](logging.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)
      v8::internal::Isolate::DumpAndResetStats() in libv8_monolith.a[172](isolate.o)

On the other hand, when I use nm to list the contents of those two files I see a list of .o entries along with their symbols. Then listing the contents of libv8_monolith.a I see many of the files from the other two archives. I didn't run a exhaustive inspection of all object file names but I suppose they must all be accounted for.
But that being said, I still can't understand why the linker can't find the symbols on the main archive file.
This is the line I used to try to compile the sample application:
g++ -std=c++17 -I. -Iinclude -Lout/x64.release/obj -o hello_world -lv8_monolith -pthread -ldl samples/hello-world.cc

And that monolith was built with the following gn arguments:
is_component_build = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
v8_enable_webassembly = false
target_cpu = "x64"
is_debug = false
clang_use_chrome_plugins = false
cc_wrapper = "ccache"
v8_static_library = true

The version of V8 I used was the tag 12.4.254.9 (based on my chrome browser version). And I had to fiddle with build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn adding this instruction cflags += ["-Wno-unused-but-set-variable"] at line 1071.
I suspect it could have something to do with the LLVM version of Apple being incompatible with the hermetic library embedded on V8.
UPDATE 2024-MAY-27
Upon closer inspection using nm --demangle out/x64.release/obj/libv8_monolith.a | grep NewDefault I found a difference between the exported function in the archive and what ld is looking for:
(2) v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__Cr::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__Cr::default_delete<v8::TracingController>>, v8::platform::PriorityMode)

(1) v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__1::default_delete<v8::TracingController>>, v8::platform::PriorityMode)

In the snippet above, (1) is displayed by nm and (2) is what ld is looking for. I noticed that some arguments are declared as members of std::__Cr while others are members of std::__1. Since I come from the Java world and my experience with native coding is next to none I can't tell if there is some significance to this.

brew install v8

It is good to know that I have this option. However, it is best to understand how to do the proper build process so I can customise it to my own needs.
